# Why does argparse fail when an option is put just before the rest of the positional parameters?

Tags: python, argparse

Consider this test argparse example in scratch.py using python 3.7.2:

```
import sys
import argparse
import yaml


def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--sound', nargs='?', default=None)
    parser.add_argument('greeting')
    parser.add_argument('name')
    parser.add_argument('params', nargs='*')
    return vars(parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:]))


def main():
    print(yaml.dump((get_args())))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If I use it:

```
(websosadmin) ~/wk/cliosoft/websosadmin/sosadmin_cli $ python scratch.py hello john loud red
greeting: hello
name: john
params:
- loud
- red
sound: null

(websosadmin) ~/wk/cliosoft/websosadmin/sosadmin_cli $ python scratch.py --sound bell hello john loud red
greeting: hello
name: john
params:
- loud
- red
sound: bell

(websosadmin) ~/wk/cliosoft/websosadmin/sosadmin_cli $ python scratch.py hello --sound bell john loud red
greeting: hello
name: john
params:
- loud
- red
sound: bell

(websosadmin) ~/wk/cliosoft/websosadmin/sosadmin_cli $ python scratch.py hello john --sound bell loud red
usage: scratch.py [-h] [--sound [SOUND]] greeting name [params [params ...]]
scratch.py: error: unrecognized arguments: loud red
```

Why does the fourth case fail?

Answer (score 1):

This answer builds on [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj)'s response.

It is a bug in argparse but there is a workaround: Replace `parse_args` with `parse_intermixed_args`.

This works in the example in the question (and in the actual application which is complex with many sub commands and different flags and positional parameters) but it may fail if things like `argparse.REMAINDER` are used.

Answer (score 0):

With

```
hello john --sound bell loud red
```

is parsed as:

```
greeting = 'hello'
name = 'john'
params = []
sound = 'bell'
```

`['loud','red']` are left over.

The parser alternatively handles positionals and a optional.  It uses a regex style of pattern matching to assign the set of positionals upto the next optional ('--sound').  'greeting' and 'name' each require one string.  'params' can accept any list ('*') including an empty one.  Once it's used up there aren't any more arguments left to consume the 'loud' and 'red'.

It's a tricky behavior, and not ideal.  There's at least one bug/issue on the topic, but if my memory is correct it's not an easy thing to patch.

Changing to `nargs='+'` should give the correct parsing.

Comment: Changing `nargs='+'` does indeed parse the fourth example correctly but its an incorrect specification because `python scratch.py hello john --sound bell` now fails instead. The intention of the params is that it can contain zero or more arguments. Do you have a link to the bug/issue?

Comment: Another option is to change it to '--parms'; using a flag gives more control.  Or `parse_known_args` to collect all 'left over' strings.

Comment: Thanks, parse_intermixed_args gives the correct answer. The real application is using cement though so I'll have to dig into that and see if I can change this without other problems emerging.

Comment: I forgot about `intermixed`.  That separates the handling of optionals and positions.  It was inteneded to allow splitting a * positional, but as a side effect cleans up this behavior.  Old optparse handled optionals, and put everything else in an extras list.